# userinfo in NSTimer iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nstimer

I want to pass some data to the fire method.So I use the 'userInfo'

I did like this:

```
struct MyStruct* userinfo = malloc(sizeof(struct MyStruct));

userinfo->a = 1;
userinfo->b = 2;

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(myFireMethod:) userInfo:userinfo repeats:YES];
```

But the problem happened,the iOS app crashed when running the `scheduledTimerWithInterval` method.

It must be something wrong with 'userinfo' .What's the probably mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userInfo has to be Objective C object, cause it's retained during assignment.

If you want to pass C-struct you have to wrap it with NSValue:

```
NSValue* val = [NSValue valueWithPointer: your_struct_ptr];
```